# Is there a minimal POSIX shell for OS X?

Tags: shell, osx, posix

Is there a minimal POSIX shell implementation for OS X? I like to write fairly portable shell scripts and want to catch as many incompatibilities or bashisms up front as I can. I'm not intending to replace the system `/bin/sh`.

`/bin/sh` on OS X `10.11.4` is GNU bash 3.2.57 or based on it.

```
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

This is the same version string that `/bin/bash` reports even though the two files differ. Why is that by the way?

```
$ diff /bin/sh /bin/bash
Binary files /bin/sh and /bin/bash differ
```

Anyway, POSIX-compatibility mode `bash` still does some things that aren't required by the standard (and aren't de facto universal like `local`), e.g. this form of brace expansion.

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Both `dash` and `yash` can be installed through Homebrew on macOS.  Also `/bin/sh` on macOS would be sufficient for running POSIX scripts. The fact that it does brace expansions etc. does not mean it's not a POSIX shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacPorts has [`dash`](https://trac.macports.org/attachment/ticket/25348/Portfile), which is what Debian uses.  For that and other choices, read *[Is there a minimally POSIX.2 compliant shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376975/is-there-a-minimally-posix-2-compliant-shell)*, in which the answers point out that the standard is vague in places.

Comment: Homebrew also has a `dash` package.

Comment: As of 10.15, macOS ships with dash.

Answer (score -1):

Along with `dash`, there is also:

> The Schily Bourne Shell was derived from the Bourne Shell sources from OpenSolaris.

Which is available on pkgin/pkgsrc.

Two options for `pkgin`:

- The minimal POSIX compliant variant (pbosh)
- The POSIX compliant extended variant (bosh)

Joyent provides macos [pkgin binary packages](https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-osx/)

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html

I haven't used it on a mac, but have used various variants of OpenSolaris.